# Annihilation Scattering Cross-Section $N_{n}+N_{n} \rightarrow \nu_{i} + \nu_{j}$

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, dark-matter, phase-space, scattering-cross-section

I'm calculating the annihilation scattering cross section for fermionic dark matter candidate. I got the following result for the squared amplitude,

$|\mathcal{M}|^2= \frac{h_{ji}f^{*}_{ij}}{(m^{2}_{{k}}-t)^{2}}(m^{2}_{n}-t)^{2}$

where this represent an scattering process in t-channel like $N_{n}+N_{n} \rightarrow \nu_{j}+\nu_{i}$ while $m_{k}$ is the mass of the scalar propagator.
How can I get the cross section from there? Assuming that the masses are at TeV scale and $m_{k}>m_{n}$.
I should get something depending of the relative velocity.
$t= m^{2}_{n}-2p_{1}p_{3}$ since I'm assuming that the outgoing particles are massless.